# Linking database data to PDF (printing of receipt) via asp.net and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

can I ask how to link database data to PDF? Like I have my own order number in my database, and I want to link the orderNo to the one in my database. Same goes to the Product and Price. Thank you.

```
string companyName = "Testing1";
int orderNo = 1234;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5]
{
   new DataColumn("ProductId", typeof(string)),
   new DataColumn("Product", typeof(string)),
   new DataColumn("Price", typeof(int)),
   new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(int)),
   new DataColumn("Total", typeof(int))
 });
```

Comment: You want to filter data based on orderNo, Product and Price?

Comment: I have page for order details and I want the order details page information to display in the pdf (receipt)

Comment: So, you want your data to be shown in pdf within the browser of order details,, right?

Comment: Yeah, right. :)

Comment: [Open PDF in Browser](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-and-display-PDF-Files-from-database-in-browser-in-ASPNet.aspx) Have a look here.

Comment: The link is not working.